# How to handle multiple Switch button React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, event-handling

I am trying to use multiple switch button in react js , I tried but i could not get positive result i want to do main button `notification` when click on notification all button should checked and also i can check or uncheck by separate button but i could not,once i checked button should checked .Here is my all code that i tried.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import config from "../Main";

import Switch from "react-switch";
import axios from "axios";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

let authToken = localStorage.getItem("Token");

class Notification extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fleet: [],
      user: [],
      checked: false,
      isHidden: "checked",
      notifications: false,
      notify_critical_overspeeding: false,
      notify_overspeeding: true,
      notify_exceeding_fuel: true,
      notify_engine_error: true,
      notify_campaign_confirmation: true,
      notify_campaign_start: false,
      notify_car_inspection: true,
      notify_insurance: false,
      notify_maintenance: true,
      receive_critical_overspeeding_email: true,
      checkedItems: new Map()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked });
  }

  toggleHidden() {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });
  }

  handleChange1 = e => {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked)
    }));
  };


  async componentDidMount() {
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem("Token");
    try {
      Promise.all([
        axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: config.apiUrl.fleetnotification,
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(authToken)
          }
        }).then(res => {
          this.setState({
            notifications: res.data.notifications,
            notify_critical_overspeeding: res.data.notify_critical_overspeeding,
            notify_overspeeding: res.data.notify_overspeeding,
            notify_exceeding_fuel: res.data.notify_exceeding_fuel,
            notify_engine_error: res.data.notify_engine_error,
            notify_campaign_confirmation: res.data.notify_campaign_confirmation,
            notify_campaign_start: res.data.notify_campaign_start,
            notify_car_inspection: res.data.notify_car_inspection,
            notify_insurance: res.data.notify_insurance,
            notify_maintenance: res.data.notify_maintenance
          });
        }),
        axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: config.apiUrl.usernotification1,
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(authToken)
          }
        }).then(res => {
          this.setState({
            receive_critical_overspeeding_email:
              res.data.receive_critical_overspeeding_email
          });
        })
      ]);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { fleet, user } = this.state;
    const { t } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "30px" }}>
        <Helmet>
          <title>notication_management</title>
        </Helmet>
        <div>


        </div>
        <div className="headerr" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
          <div className="" style={{ margin: "auto" }}>
            <div className="row">
              <div
                class=" col-sm-6 "
                style={{ marginTop: "0px", margin: "auto" }}
              >
                <div
                  // class="loml"
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    fontSize: "15px"
                  }}
                >
                  <strong class="float-left font-weight-bold h5">
                    NOTIFICATION
                  </strong>
                  <small
                    className="float-right"
                    style={{ position: "relative", top: "-12px" }}
                  >
                    <label class="switch">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="togBtn"
                        onClick={this.toggleHidden}
                      />
                      <div class="slider round"></div>
                    </label>
                  </small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            {/* All Notification List here */}
            <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
              <div
                class=" col-sm-6 "
                style={{
                  marginTop: "20px",
                  margin: "auto"
                }}
              >
                <div
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    fontSize: "15px"
                  }}
                >
                  <strong class="float-left font-weight-bold">
                    Critical overspeeding
                  </strong>
                  <small
                    className="float-right"
                    style={{ position: "relative", top: "-12px" }}
                  >
                    <Switch
                      onChange={e => this.handleChange1(e)}
                      checked={this.state.checked}
                    />
                  </small>
                </div>
                <hr></hr>

                <div
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    fontSize: "15px"
                  }}
                >
                  <strong class="float-left font-weight-bold">
                    Overspeeding
                  </strong>
                  <small
                    className="float-right"
                    style={{ position: "relative", top: "-12px" }}
                  >
                    <Switch
                      onChange={e => this.handleChange1(e)}
                      // checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.name) || false}
                    />
                  </small>
                </div>
                <hr></hr>

                <div
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px",
                    fontSize: "15px"
                  }}
                >
                  <strong class="float-left font-weight-bold">
                    Exceeding fuel consumption
                  </strong>
                  <small
                    className="float-right"
                    style={{ position: "relative", top: "-12px" }}
                  >
                    <Switch onChange={e => this.handleChange1(e)} />
                  </small>
                </div>
                <hr></hr>





              </div>
            </div>

            {/*End All Notification List here */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Notification;
```